# как проверить закончились ли символы в файле?

Tags: c++, итераторы

делаю итератор по файлу:

```
#ifndef FILEITERATOR_CPP
#define FILEITERATOR_CPP

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

template <class T>
class FileIterator {
private:
    std::string fileName;
    char symbol;
    std::string words;
    std::ifstream in;
public:
    FileIterator(std::string nameFile) : fileName(nameFile) {
        in(nameFile);
    }

    void next() {
        if(over()) {
            return;
        }

        for ( ; in.get(symbol); ) {
            words += symbol;
        }
    }

    void operator++() {
        next();
    }

    void operator++(int) {
        operator++();
    }

    bool over() {
        return 
    }

    T value() {
        return words;
    }

    int operator*() {
        return value();
    }
};
```

при создание итератора даю название файла где нужно пройтись и считать все символы.Но не понимаю как остановить итератор и дать ему понять что все символы считаны.Для этого у меня есть метод `bool over()` где я должен : `return smth`,чтобы понять что можно заканчивать программу.
Но как это сделать?

Comment: Считать очередной символ. Если не считан, проверить `eof()` и вернуть соответствующий флаг. Если считан — вернуть назад в поток с помощью `.unget()` (но неэффективно). Или — изначально посмотреть, сколько в файле символов (его размер), и отслеживать текущий указатель файла (но теряется возможность расшаренного дописывания файла другой программой, например).

Answer (score -1):

```
#include "stdio.h"
...
while(!feof(f))
{
    doSomething();
}
```

f - файловый поток

Comment: [Почему `while (!feof(f))` - всегда ошибка?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2752075)

Comment: eof не использовал, писал всегда feof, и не забудь !

Comment: while(!feof(f))

Comment: Угу, название с опечаткой перевел, исправил. Но проблема никуда не делась.

Comment: убедись, что stdio.h подключено и еще раз пересмотри синтаксис

Comment: Файловый поток подключен, все хорошо?

Comment: :) Я не спрашивал вас, почему ошибка. Я вам намекаю, что цикл, который вы предлагаете - сломан. Открывайте ссылку и читайте, почему так.

Comment: Извини, не видел. Если честно, не понял в чем проблема в статье. У меня всегда все отлично работало

Comment: Вот [пример](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1sWbbMPsq). Цикл выполняется на один раз больше, чем нужно.

Comment: сделай проверку в цикле:
if(str[strlen(str)-1]=='\n') 
{
    str[strlen(str)-1] = '\0';
}

Comment: str - считанная строка